# How to copy and paste in VBA without copying and pasting blank rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that does almost exactly what I need it to do which is to copy and paste from one worksheet to another. Here is the code.

`ADM.Range("A6", ("A" & Rows.Count)).Copy Destination:=Pricing.Range("A3")`

However, the issue I am having is that it also copy and pastes the blank rows so that I have a spreadsheet that has over 1 million rows. If I am copying and pasting 100 rows for example, I want the code to only copy and paste those 100 rows and not the 1 million plus. This is an issue for me because I need to autofill formulas and having 1 million plus rows causes the code to fail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you Filter/Sort before copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `("A" & Rows.Count)` to:

```
ADM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

so:

```
ADM.Range("A6", ADM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Pricing.Range("A3")
```

Comment: @GCC please come back and mark as correct after the question is 15 minutes old.  You do so by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: It told me I had to wait 4 minutes but I just did it now.